# GCP Cloud Shell Command Equivalent For Python SDK

Tags: python, api, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-stackdriver

I have command to retrieve stackdriver logs in specific file and it is as below,

```
gcloud logging read "resource.type=\"bigquery_resource\" AND timestamp >= \"2019-12-03T00:00:00Z\" AND timestamp <= \"2019-12-04T05:30:00Z\" AND protoPayload.serviceData.jobCompletedEvent.job.jobStatistics.totalBilledBytes > 0" --format json > logs_data.json
```

Willing to know if their is any other way to do the same, using python script or python SDK for GCP.

Answer (score 4):

You can find the sample python code example [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/logging/cloud-client/snippets.py#L55). The REST API method used to retrieve log entries would be [entries.list](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/entries/list).

For more details on how to setup python to talk to GCP Stackdriver: https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/quickstart-python

Hope this helps.

Comment: payload method of list_entries doesn't provide that enough insights as view method of shell does... thanks for your comments...

Comment: @AmrishMishra - Can you clarify your comment? The CLI `gcloud` uses the same APIs to pull the same data. This is the correct answer.

Comment: "gcloud logging read" is different from client.list_entries(). You can verify the details. I wished if we can have read method in SDK.